# fine-uploader how to get the response from chunking success?

Tags: fine-uploader

How can i get the response of the chunking success url:

I can see it the response in the console using the debug but I can't get it with the callbacks.

Here is my code:

```js
// Some options to pass to the uploader are discussed on the next page
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById("uploader"),
    debug: true,
    retry: {
       enableAuto: false, // defaults to false
       showButton:true
    },
    request: {
        endpoint: '{{ hls_video_upload_form.action }}',
        params: {
            // user_kind: '{{ hls_video_upload_form.user_kind }}',
            // user_ref: '{{ hls_video_upload_form.user_ref }}'
            user_ref: $("input[name=user_ref]").val(), // USER_REF from Form
            user_kind: $("input[name=user_kind]").val()  // USER_KIND from Form
        }
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true,
        mandatory: true,
        concurrent: {
            enabled: true
        },
        success: {
            endpoint: '/onCOMPLETE_UPLOAD'
            // I WANT THE RESPONSE OF THESE

        }
    },
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, response, xhr) {
            console.log(response);

        },
        onUploadChunkSuccess : function(id, chunkData, response, xhr) {
            console.log(response);

        }

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about the various callbacks. `onUploadChunkSuccess`, [as the documentation states](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#uploadChunkSuccess), will be called for *each* chunk after the chunk has successfully uploaded. But according to your code, you are not looking for this. Instead, you want Fine Uploader to call a specific endpoint once all chunks have been uploaded, and then you require access to the response to that request in a callback. [The documentation page for the concurrent chunking feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/concurrent-chunking.html) (which you have enabled) explains how to obtain the response to this request:

> **Expected response for the chunking success POST**
>
> For successful responses, you may return an empty body with a status
>   of 200-204. Any other status code is determined to be a failure. You
>   can also return a JSON response with any data your would like passed
>   to your onComplete handler. Furthermore, you can include an error
>   property in your response with the error message you would like to
>   have displayed next to the failed file (if you are using Fine Uploader
>   UI).